# Linker error for compiler-generated functions in package class in BPL

Tags: c++builder, c++builder-10.4-sydney

I'm trying to move our projects from the Classic compiler to the Clang compiler.

When linking a package `.bpl` file,  it complains about missing constructors, destructors, and assignment operators. These are all cases where the specific function was not declared and is implicitly generated by the compiler when needed.

One of the errors is:

> [Linker Error] Error: Unresolved external 'MplusPostgres::PgParams::~PgParams()' referenced from C:...\DEBUG_BUILD\PGUTIL.OBJ

The destructor mentioned `~PgParams` has not been declared in the `PgParams` class.

I can solve it by explicitly implementing the missing functions, but to do that for all classes in all the packages would be a significant amount of work, even when using the `default` keyword.

Is there another way that is less work to make these errors go away?

Comment: Are the *.bpl files packages that you have written in "classic" C++? What version of C++ Builder are you using ?

Comment: @RogerCigol we are currently on 10.4.2 (sydney). Packages have originally been created with older version (we have had several versions through the years)

Comment: Are you recompiling all of the BPLs in the new version? You can't reuse BPL binaries from older versions.

Comment: @RemyLebeau, yes I know, I'm rebuilding everything.

Comment: Although I don't recognise the precise problem you describe, you should be warned that there are known issues with C++ based packages using clang compilers in 10.4.2 and earlier versions. I have some packages written in Classic C++ and I am forced to use Classic C++ for the projects that use these packages.  I have good reason to believe that these problems have been resolved in the forthcoming version 11 which should be out soon.